# Want to develop rails site offline then move to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an issue with developing my site on my macbook and then moving to a server when done? Will there be issues I need to plan ahead for? DB or ruby related maybe? Dependencies or something a server could have different from my dev environment that could cause a nightmare later? I'd rather develop it offline since it'd be faster and wouldn't require an internet connection but in the past I've always done everything with live sites so this would be a first, and I am new to ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing locally and then deploying to your server(s) via something like capistrano  is standard practise.

It's a good idea to keep your development environment as close as possible to your production environment (ruby versions, database versions etc). Bundler makes keeping your gems in sync easy

Answer (score 0):

I used Heroku for some projects. The deployment was as easy as it could be. I just did a `git push` and it worked without problems... I really like bundler and rake :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question embodies THE way to develop in Rails. Your development environment is an offline representation of what you're production site will be.

A quick workflow analysis for you could be:

`rails new ~/my_app -d postgresql; cd ~/my_app; rm public/index.html`

Next, create the database:

`bundle exec rake db:create:all`

Now you'll have the db and app all set up, let's set up your main pages:

`bundle exec rails generate controller Site index about_us contact_us`

Now you'll have something to see on the site, so run:

`bundle exec rails server`

This server acts as your offline connection and will handle the rendering of any text, images, html etc you want to serve in your rails app. Now you can join in the debates of TDD, to TATFT or JITT, rspec vs test::unit. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Developing locally is definitely the way to go.  However, I would look into getting it on production as soon as possible and pushing often.  This way you can see changes happen as you make them and are aware of any possible breaking changes.

I use heroku a lot and when I start a new project I push it to heroku almost immediately.  While developing, I can publish new changes simply by `git push heroku master`.  Everyone has to find their own workflow, but this has always worked well for me.

If you are interested in Heroku here is a good link to get you started:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3